# Python - CSV - Calculate average of column values by a column id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a very large CSV file that I managed to order by a column id, but I cannot calculate the average column values that have that column id.

```
88741,42.84286022,16.41829224,1
88797,42.78081536,16.40743455,1
88797,42.78081536,16.21153455,1
88823,42.51512511,16.43304948,2
88885,42.88204193,16.12412548,2
87227,42.88204193,16.64223948,3
and so on...
```

I need to get a new csv without the SchoolCode column, and with the Lat and Long averaged for each cluster. And also, the digits number should be the same. I tried pandas it throws me this error.

The output should be something like this:

```
Lat,Long,Cluster
<average_lat_forCluster1>,<average_long_forCluster1>,1
<average_lat_forCluster2>,<average_long_forCluster2>,2
<average_lat_forCluster3>,<average_long_forCluster3>,3
and so on...
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('SortedCluster.csv', names=[
             'SchoolCode', 'Lat', 'Long', 'Cluster'])
df2 = df.groupby('Cluster')['Lat','Long'].mean()
df2.to_csv('AverageOutput.csv')
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "averager.py", line 6, in <module>
    df2 = df.groupby('Cluster')['Lat','Long'].mean()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1306, in mean
    return self._cython_agg_general('mean', **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 3974, in _cython_agg_general
    how, alt=alt, numeric_only=numeric_only, min_count=min_count)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 4046, in _cython_agg_blocks
    raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Comment: Do you  want `df.groupby('Cluster')['Lat','Long'].mean()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe need convert values to numeric first if necessary:

```
df[['Lat','Long']] = df[['Lat','Long']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

And then aggregate `mean` per groups:

```
df.groupby('Cluster')['Lat','Long'].mean()
```

Comment: sorry. I forgot the headers inside the file. I edited my question if you can review it

Comment: Wht is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: where? I don't see it. I don't have that line

Comment: You can add thhis line under `df = pd.read_csv('SortedCluster.csv')`

Comment: it prints this:
```['88741', '42.84286022', '16.41829224', '1']```

Comment: It means there is no csv header, so need `df = pd.read_csv('SortedCluster.csv', names = ['SchoolCode','Lat','Long','Cluster'])`

Comment: Now I get ```no numerical values to aggregate```, because it takes the names for the first row

Comment: @GabrielMoncea - Do you try `df[['Lat','Long']] = df[['Lat','Long']].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')` from my solution?